# Finding all roles for a particular resource instance in Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rolify

How do I find all roles for a particular resource instance in Rolify? The [documentation](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) suggests the following:

```
Forum.find_roles
# => [ list of roles that binded to any Forum instance or to the Forum class ]
```

But what if I want a particular `Forum` instance? `Forum.first.find_roles` does not work. Is there another way? This is what I tried with `Location` instead of `Forum`:

```
2.1.5 :003 > Location.first.find_roles
  Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations"  ORDER BY "locations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_roles' for #<Location:0x007fbe880d1b48>
    from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activemodel-4.2.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Location.first.roles` should work.

Reference: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#instance-level